# Retrieve a parent with filtered children in Core Data

Tags: swift, core-data

I have a core data objects as follows:

```
class Parent: PLManagedObject {
    @NSManaged public var id: String?
    @NSManaged public var child: NSSet?
}

class Child: PLManagedObject {
    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    @NSManaged public var parent: Parent?
}
```

The relation type between `Parent` and `Child` object is one-to-many.

I am looking for a predicate on `Parent` to be able to retrieve it with filtered set of `Child` based on an attribute of `Child`. Something like this:

```
return NSPredicate(format: "Any child.name == %@", nameString)
```

Are we able to do that with any sort of predicate?

Comment: If you fetch `Parent` objects, each comes with all its related `Child` objects.  There's no way to for a fetch request on Parent to filter the Child objects. You can filter the child objects in memory as a separate step, or use a separate fetch for the Child objects, as @vadian proposes in his answer.

Comment: @Soheil Novinfard Did you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to fetch `Child` items with a specific parent `id`

```
NSPredicate(format: "parent.id == %@ AND name == %@", parentID, nameString)
```

If you want to get all `Parent` items which contain the child with given name fetch the `Child` objects and `map` them

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", nameString)
let children = context.fetch(fetchRequest)
let parentItems = children.map { $0.parent }
```

Comment: I knew about this already, but as I mentioned it doesn't give me parent objects with filtered related child objects, it is what I am looking for.

Comment: Your topic is *Retrieve **a** parent with...*. Please see the edit.